# Shape of feces in herbivores

Tags: zoology, digestive-system, excreta

Why do some herbivores like sheep, cow, and others excrete feces in a pellet (or biscuit or other) shape, while other species including humans do not do so? What is the reason for such an adaptation in herbivores? Is it beneficial to them, and if so, how?

Comment: perhaps there is role of  microbes as well as whole process of digestion.

Comment: Goats are also herbivores but their dung is bead like, and not soft as cow-dung

Comment: I think it has something to do with how the different animals move the feces with peristalsis

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is an adaption, but the that diet plays a dominant role. The feces of cows in intensively fertilized agricultural fields, with grasses rich in protein, has no shape at all. See picture below.
[image]

[The feces of cows in natural areas has much more structure.](http://zalix.nl/fotografie/dieren/koeien/028786-ovps1-koeienvlaai-schotse-hooglander.php) (image has copyright, so can only link)

Comment: Please have the courtesy to explain your downvote?!